# Difference between by/ with

Tags: prepositions

I am not a native speaker. So how should I write properly:

> write by English letters

or

> write with English letters?

Or may be I should use another word?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by English letters.

Comment: It was just an example of a question, like : "You should write by/with english letters!"

Comment: What English letters? Do you mean "Write in English"?

Comment: So it was a question " Why do you write by/with english letters?" (On the keyboard layout) i can also ask :" why do you write by/with russian letters or chinese letters

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I am totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

'Write *with* English letters', as opposed to say 'with Russian (Cyrillic) letters'.

Or 'write *in* English' and not in Russian or in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

You write English **using** the letters of the English (or Latin) alphabet. Or **in** the English alphabet.